# Exponential Random Variable question regarding property

Tags: probability

I am fairly new to this site. Below I show my question.

Consider $T$ an exponential random variable. Show

$$\mathbb{P}[T>s+t|T>s] = P[T>t]$$

I use Bayes rule 
$$\mathbb{P}[T>s+t|T>s]= \frac{\mathbb{P}[T>s+t]}{P[T>s]}= \frac{1-e^{-\lambda(s+t)}}{1-e^{-\lambda s}}$$

Is the way I proceed correct.

Comment: Actually there is a little mistake. $$P(T<t)= \mathrm (1-e^{-\lambda t})$$
So:
 $$P(T>t)= 1-\mathrm (1-e^{-\lambda t})=e^{-\lambda t}$$
If you fix it the demostration would be good.

Comment: thanks you are right, should I directly edit or should you right it in the anseer and I accept?

Comment: @rlartiga write it as an answer so that Richard can accept it. Just to avoid having a unanswered question

Comment: @Richard ok I made an answer

Comment: @VladimirVargas ok I made it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a little mistake.
$$P(T<t)=(1−e^{−\lambda t})$$
So:
$$P(T>t)=1−(1−e^{-\lambda t})=e^{-\lambda t}$$

Then in your demostration:
$$\mathbb{P}[T>s+t|T>s]= \frac{\mathbb{P}[T>s+t]}{P[T>s]}= \frac{e^{-\lambda(s+t)}}{e^{-\lambda s}}=e^{-\lambda t}$$